# Unity Vectors Equality

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

{
Hi guys,
So here's my problem, I am pretty new on programming in unity and I've recently made my first game for android.
It's a pretty simple 2D game with infinite up to down scrolling and you have to dodge the fallings blocks.
I have made my little C# script that should make the player go to the opposite side of the screen when it goes out of it.
The thing is it is working pretty well when I use it in unity but when I port it to apk file it doesn't work at all :(.
Here's my code:

Thanks for helping me :)

```
if (player.transform.position == new Vector3 (8, -7, 0)) 
        {
            transform.Translate (-15, 0, 0);
        }

if (player.transform.position == new Vector3 (-8, -7, 0)) 
        {
            transform.Translate (15, 0, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use == for Vector3 variables... they're based on floating point numbers which can be very close to each other but still not equal.

Instead try checking whether player.transform.position.x is greater than 8 or less than -8. Your game should work more consistently this way.

Comment: Thank  you, it works now I've just posted my game on play store if you guys are interrested search for geometric project. ;)